# CSS3 consistent animation speed

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I want my leaf animate towards certain directions while slowing down its speed. I tried using ease-out to implement this effect. However, this causes my leaf to ease-out when going one direction (from 0% to 75%) and once again when going another direction (at 75% to 100%).

How do I make my leaf go directions and constantly slow down (not ease-out at every turn)?

```
#leaf {         
    height:100px;
    width:100px;

    animation: leaf 10s infinite ease-out;                                          
    -webkit-animation: leaf 10s infinite ease-out;                                  
}                                                                                   

@keyframes leaf {                                                                   
    0% {                                                                        
            transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);                         
    }                                                                           
    75% {                                                                       
            transform: translate(200px, 300px) rotateZ(270deg);                 
    }                                                                           
    100% {                                                                      
            transform: translate(0px, 600px) rotateZ(360deg);                   
    }                                                                           
}                                                                                   

@-webkit-keyframes leaf {                                                           
    0% {                                                                        
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);                 
    }                                                                           
    75% {                                                                       
            -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 300px) rotateZ(270deg);         
    }                                                                           
    100% {                                                                      
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 600px) rotateZ(360deg);           
    }                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are using is [`ease-out`](http://jsfiddle.net/8YbLU/2/) but what you need is [`animation-timing-function: linear;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8YbLU/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I apologize if I did not explain my problem clearly. I have an animation path as you can see from my code. I want the leaf to follow that path and slowing down at the same time. At the moment, it is fast-slow going to one direction, then fast-slow again when going another direction. I want it to constantly slow down while falling, not having bursts of speed somewhere "mid-animation".

Comment: for path you can try using skrollr or jQuery Scroll Path

Comment: @MarcoLau you will have to use jQuery for that, CSS won't do alone for you, look out for jquery path

Comment: @Mr.Alien I tried using jquery path and it is not responding to my code. I want to confirm if I have the right plugin. Did you mean [weepy's jquery.path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but the math is not easy. 
I get it just by trial and error.

You need to set a timing function for each step, and somehow adapt it to your needs.

A demo:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

.leaf {         
    animation: leafa 10s infinite ease-out;                                          
    -webkit-animation: leaf 10s infinite ease-out;                                  
    animation: leaf 10s infinite ease-out;                                  
    background-color: aqua;
}                                                                                   

.mark {         
    animation: mark 10s infinite ease-out;                                          
    -webkit-animation: mark 10s infinite ease-out;                                  
    animation: mark 10s infinite ease-out;                                  
    border: solid 1px blue;
}                                                                                   


@-webkit-keyframes leaf {                                                           
    0% {    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);   
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.6);
    }                                                                           
    35% {   -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);         
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.765, 0.6, 0.8);
    }                                                                           
    100% {  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);           
    }                                                                           
}  

@-webkit-keyframes mark {                                                           
    0% {    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);       }                                                                           
    100% {  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);     }                                                                           
} 

@keyframes leaf {                                                           
    0% {    transform: translateX(0px);   
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.4, 0.45, 0.6);
    }                                                                           
    35% {   transform: translateX(200px);         
            animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.765, 0.6, 0.8);
    }                                                                           
    100% {  transform: translateX(400px);           
    }                                                                           
}  

@keyframes mark {                                                           
    0% {    transform: translateX(0px);       }                                                                           
    100% {  transform: translateX(400px);     }                                                                           
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsX7D/)

The mark has an standard ease out animation over the full transform. The leaf has 2 segments, and each one of them has a cubic bezier timing function.

The result is that the leaf almost matches the mark. It can be done as good as you want, it's only a matter of trying (or knowing more math that I do).

You can find [this link](http://www.css3beziercurve.net/) useful.